# How can I pass a value from one SSRS subreport to another subreport under the same parent report

Tags: reporting-services, visual-studio-2013

I'm trying to pass a value created in a subreport expression to another subreport. Is it possible? How can it be done?

Here is the report structure:

Parent Report - gets Head Office ID as a parameter

Head Office Subreport - Uses parameter to display data including YearEnd in a text box `TextBoxYE`.

Tablix that looks up all branch office IDs of the head office (based on parameter value).

Branch Office subreport within Tablix displays report for each branch office.

Issue: Branch Office Subreport needs to display YearEnd of Head Office.

I've tried using a global variable but can't figure out how (or if I can) set the value of the variable in the Head Office subreport. Even though there is only one record in the data set, setting it within an expression in the Head Office report, every way I try to reference the field in the dataset  (MAX(First(YearEnd, (First(YearEnd and (YearEnd all throw various aggregation errors.

I tried ReportItems but that doesn't work outside the current scope of the dataset/report, so I don't think that can be used to reference a TextBox in another subreport.

Is there way to pass the value in TextBox `TextBoxYE.Value` from one subreport to another?

Thanks,

Comment: To clarify -- you are nesting two subreports into a parent report and each subreport uses a different dataset?  Or the same?  Can you provide the expression you are using to populate `TextBoxYE`?  And finally, are you saying that the same expression doesn't work in the parent report?

Comment: There are two subreports (Head Office and Branch Office) on the parent report, it is not one subreport inside another. They use different, shared datasets. 

Expression for ```TextBoxYE``` is ```=MonthName(Val(LEFT(Fields!YEAR_END.Value,2))) + ", " + Right(Fields!YEAR_END.Value,2) + "."``` which for example converts 1231 to December, 31.

I haven't tried that expression in the parent report because that field isn't in it's dataset.

Comment: I guess my suggestion would be to add the relevant dataset to the second subreport.  There's no reason you can't have multiple datasets -- regardless of their usage.  Just make sure to add the relevant parameters to the subreport object in the parent report and you should be able to use the same expression.

Comment: I guess I'll go with that. Thanks for the suggestion.